# Share project settings of IntelliJ IDEA in SVN

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I want to share the project settings from IntelliJ IDEA in a Maven project over SVN. For example, the automatic download of JavaDoc and Sources for dependencies.

I think the settings are stored to `..\.idea\workspace.xml`, but in the IntelliJ docs, I have read, that the workspace.xml should be ignored on SVN.

How can I share these project settings? Settings Sync is a cloud solution and Settings Repository needs a Git repository. Both are not possible for me at the moment.

Link to docs: [IntelliJ IDEA Documentation | Configure project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html#list-of-ignored-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - `workspace.xml` stores user-specific and machine-specific settings and it is generally not a good idea to share it via a VCS.

In regards to the Maven settings located in the `workspace.xml` - there is a [YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259064/Maven-preferences-that-must-be-shared-but-located-in-workspace.xml) for that, which you can upvote and leave a comment with your use-case scenario to rise its' priority for the developers.